# permission denied when opening python script from php

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a PHP script that will create and append data to a text document.  The script will then execute a python script that will read over that document, and move create a different document else where on the raspberry pi.  I have been looking for the past several hours at different solutions, and they all seem to boil down to permissions.  Based on what I have found, I have set the following:

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   314 Jan  9 16:09 AlbumString.py
>
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 74 Jan  9 21:31 display.txt

The AlbumString.py is the python script, the display.txt is where the PHP file rights to, and the Python script reads from.  Further research somone suggested looking at the error logs for apache.  When I looked at this I saw that I was getting a permission error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AlbumString.py", line 13, in <module>
    display = open('/media/pi/external/Photos/' + templist.pop(0),'a')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/pi/external/Photos/Erik.txt'
```

My python code will create or append a file if it already exists.  In the case of running this iteration, the file Erik.txt did not exist, so it would have had to create it.
The code for AlbumString.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import json
import base64

album = open('/var/www/html/uploads/display.txt')
templist = []
a= 0
for x in album:
    templist.append(x.rstrip('\n'))
album.close()
display = open('/media/pi/external/Photos/' + templist.pop(0),'a')
for x in templist:
    display.write(x+'\n')
display.close()
```

The PHP code that I am using to call the python script:

```
fclose($fh);
$testing = shell_exec("python3 AlbumString.py");
if(!$testing){
    echo "You are a failure!<br>";
} else {
    echo "You are a genius<br>";
}
      echo "end of document";
}
```

I have also added www-data to my sudoers file, which is not suggested but that I would give it a chance, and nothing has worked.  The PHP correctly writes to the file, and if I call the python script from a console, that properly executes as well.

Comment: DO NOT add apache to your sudoers file if you value your security. If you do, you still have to call "sudo command-whatever" to actually work as su.

Comment: Also, if your script is having permission problems creating a new file Erik.txt in the directory /media/pi/external/Photos, then www-data will probably need permission to write that directory. What do you get when you type "ls -al /media/pi/external/Photos" ?

Comment: when I do "ls -al /media/pi/external/Photos, all the files in that directory have the same permissions and groups:
-rw------- 1 pi pi.  If I am thinking correctly, I need to change the group of the directory and all subsequent files & folders to www-data, correct?

Comment: oops, i meant "ls -dal /media/pi/external/Photos" (notice the "d")

Comment: Anyways, I think you know what I'm getting at. Your web server user (www-data) might not have write permission for /media/pi/external/Photos. If it does not, it will not be able to create any new files in that directory.

Comment: Thank you, I think I see the errors of my way.  One last follow up question, if I change the group permissions so the server can access the directory, will I still be able to have other scripts and programs access the directory that are not related to the server?  for example say abc.py needs to access a file there, but it is saved on the desktop, would it still be able to access?

Comment: That would depend on what user is running abc.py. If you are executing abc.py by having www-data call it then everything is probably OK. If PaulCarlson is running abc.py and the directory is owned PaulCarlson::www-data and is 77x then yes you'll be fine. If you need more than two distinct users to be able to access the file, you either have to a) grant *everyone* access OR b) you have to define a new group that contains the users who need access to the file and add those users to the group and change the group ownership on the file. Permissions 101 lol